# For loop and .remove acting differently with same type / data

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to remove 'canBeGuessed' list items from the 'sortedList' items. The below code does that:

```
canBeGuessed = ['A', 'B', 'C']
SORTED_FREQUENCIES = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'
sortedList = list(SORTED_FREQUENCIES)

for letter in SORTED_FREQUENCIES:
    if letter not in canBeGuessed:
        sortedList.remove(letter)

print(f"New sorted List: {sortedList}")
```

Output:
New sorted List: ['B', 'C', 'A']

My question is, why doesn't this work when you change SORTED_FREQUENCIES to sortedList in the for loop? 'letter' in the for loop is the same type/output for both variables:

```
canBeGuessed = ['A', 'B', 'C']
SORTED_FREQUENCIES = 'ZQXJKVBPYGFWMUCLDRHSNIOATE'
sortedList = list(SORTED_FREQUENCIES)

for letter in sortedList:
    if letter not in canBeGuessed:
        sortedList.remove(letter)

print(f"New sorted List: {sortedList}")
```

Output:
New sorted List: ['Q', 'J', 'V', 'B', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'C', 'D', 'H', 'N', 'O', 'A', 'E']

I've checked the output and type of 'letter' and they are the same when looping over SORTED_FREQUENCIES and sortedList.

Comment: In your second code fragment you are modifying a list that you're iterating over. That will invariably not work. You should step through it with your favourite debugger to understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating the list while you're iterating over it. The first approach worked, because `SORTED_FREQUENCIES` remained unchanged during the loop, while in the second `sortedList` gets modified. After the first iteration, Z is removed, and the second iteration skips Q, now at index 0, to X, now at index 1.

A quick solution would be to use list slicing to create a copy of the list:

```py
for letter in sortedList[:]:
    if letter not in canBeGuessed:
        sortedList.remove(letter)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've read all the responses here but can't vote yet.

Comment: You should mark the best solution to your problem as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

here is what is happening

- The loop starts with the first element, 'Z', at index 0.
- 'Z' is not in canBeGuessed, so it should be removed. However, the removal of 'Z' shifts all the remaining elements by one position to the left.
- The loop moves to the next element, 'Q', but the current index (1) no longer corresponds to 'Q'. 'Q' was originally at index 1 but got shifted to index 0 due to the removal of 'Z'.
- The loop continues with the shifted indices, leading to incorrect comparisons and removals. As a result, elements that should have been removed are skipped.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've read all the responses here but can't vote yet.

Answer (score 1):

Removing an entry from the list while iterating over it causes some entries to be skipped, since they take the position of the removed entry. Therefore, when you remove Z, Q takes the position of Z and in the next iteration, X instead of Q will be processed.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've read all the responses here but can't vote yet.